# Calling smart contract: "header not found" in Truffle Suite

Tags: solidity, truffle, ganache

I'm trying to get Smart Contract development and testing up and running on my computer. I have a contract (based on Truffle sample code) built and deployed to a local Ganache blockchain. Can't call methods on the contract.  Error is `Uncaught Error: header not found`. Does anybody have any ideas on how to debug this error or what layer it comes from (Ethereum? Ganache?  Truffle?).

Contract code (irrelevant bits chopped out):

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.9.0;

contract HelloBlockchain {
    
    .....
    
    string public ResponseMessage;

    .....

    function getRequestMessage() view external returns(string memory) {
        return RequestMessage;
    }
}
```

Truffle CLI session results:

```
user@host sample % truffle console
truffle(development)> const instance = await HelloBlockchain.deployed();
undefined
truffle(development)> const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
undefined
truffle(development)> const result = await instance.getRequestMessage(accounts[0]);
Uncaught Error: header not found
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:1:26
    at evalmachine.<anonymous>:2:48
    at sigintHandlersWrap (node:vm:270:12)
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:139:14)
    at runScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:497:1)
    at Console.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/console.js:512:1)
    at bound (node:domain:433:15)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (node:domain:444:12)
    at REPLServer.onLine (node:repl:902:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at REPLServer.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at REPLServer.[_onLine] [as _onLine] (node:internal/readline/interface:422:12)
    at REPLServer.[_line] [as _line] (node:internal/readline/interface:892:18)
    at REPLServer.[_ttyWrite] [as _ttyWrite] (node:internal/readline/interface:1270:22)
    at REPLServer.self._ttyWrite (node:repl:997:9)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (node:internal/readline/interface:270:20)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ReadStream.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at emitKeys (node:internal/readline/utils:357:14)
    at emitKeys.next (<anonymous>) {
  code: -32700,
  hijackedStack: 'Error: header not found\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:25:1\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/provider/wrapper.js:165:1\n' +
    '    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:124:1\n' +
    '    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)'
}
truffle(development)>
```

Comment: What versions of truffle, ganache, etc. do you use? Did your contract deploy successfully? On which OS are you developing?

Comment: Hi, ahanks for replying!!  Contact deploys fine.  Versions are:

`% truffle -v
Truffle v5.7.4 (core: 5.7.4)
Ganache v7.7.3
Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js)
Node v18.13.0
Web3.js v1.8.1`

I started on MacOS Ventura and then tried Windows 11 using WSL...